# Error: invalid operands of types 'int' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator<='

Tags: c++, syntax-error

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while( t-- ) {
        int n, x = 0;
        cin >> n;
        if(n % 2 == 0)
            cout << n/2 <<" "<< n/2 << endl;
        else
            int min = INT_MAX;
        for(int i = 1; i*i <= n; i++) {
            if(( n-i) % i == 0) {
                int d = (n-i) / i;
                if(d <= min) {
                    min = d;
                    x = i;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << x <<" "<< n-x <<endl;    
    }
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

The code gives some typical error which I am failing to deal with.

Please can anyone help me fix it.

> C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Code\hello.cpp:21:20: error: invalid operands of types 'int'
> and '' to binary 'operator<='
> 21 |                if(d<=min)
> |                   ~^~~~~

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- Don't do this.  Include the proper headers, not this one.

Comment: If you wrote the code using proper C++ style, you would see [the error clearly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70305d34949a618f).  That means getting rid of the `bits` header, getting rid of the `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you missed `{}` for `else` case in:

```
else
    int min=INT_MAX;
    for(int i=1;i*i<=n;i++)
```

Because of that, the scope of `int min` is limited to the single line where it is defined. In `if(d<=min)`, the compiler is seeing `std::min()` function template instead (this is because you wrote `using namespace std;` which is not recommended).

Comment: Thank you very much i got it corrected now.